# Python : How to read every line of a paragraph and copy the line which has a specific word

Tags: python

There is a paragraph I need to read and I neded to copy the line which only has the keyword.

Paragraph is something like this:

```
aa
a
aaa
aaaaa
[new,aaa] < name of the file with path ] //asabbsjk
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
[mod] <name of the file with path
```

My algorithm:

```
if keyword exists in the line :
      copy that line 
else: 
      leave it
```

Comment: are you reading that paragraph from a file?

Comment: And what is the question? You pseudo-code looks fine.

Comment: Why are you posting pseudocode instead of your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this couple lines of code:

```
copy_lines= []
for line in paragraph.split('\n'):
    if keyword in line:
        copy_lines.append(line)
print(copy_lines)
```

or one liner:

```
copy_lines= [line for line in paragraph.split('\n') if keyword in line]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

I get the following error when i do it.

Comment: did you copied the first line too? `copy_lines= []`

Comment: Then you forgot the first line.

Comment: I have the first line too.. but still it shows me the same error!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read the paragraph from a file:

```
keyword = "your_keyword"

with open("demofile.txt", "r") as f:
    line_list = f.readlines()
    magic_lines = [line for line in line_list if keyword in line]
```